# Restrict access to certain azure functions endpoints (REST API)

Tags: api, rest, azure-functions

I am experimenting with Azure Functions and stumbled upon concept that I don't really know how to implement properly.
I have Serverless REST Api with Azure functions which contains different endpoints. Only one of this endpoint is meant to be public aka for customers (e.g. GET /api/items) but it also contains different endpoints that need to be triggered only from code like /api/items/sync, /api/items/external and similar. For now I have HTTP Trigger that makes request to /api/items/sync but this endpoint is also available for others aka no restrictions. I know that Azure Functions has Function & Master Keys. Is there a way how to limit these endpoints so they would work only if called from Azure Functions (Like HTTP Trigger) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've received answer from "Azure Architect" slack. Azure has API Management Service which allows to secure certain endpoints and is probably the best way how to handle Azure Functions (and not only them) endpoints for public. What I've done is limited my Serverless API (Azure Function REST API) to "**Function**" auth type and added API Management service with appropriate route. So my Azure Function is now accessible through API Management Service and Azure Functions endpoints are not explicit.